# What is the function of で in 「家に帰らないで映画を観に行った」?

Tags: particle-で, copula

In the sentence

> 昨日は授業の後、**家に帰らないで**映画を観に行った。

Is で the て-form of だ? Or is it the で particle? In either case, wouldn't the clause before it (家に帰らない) need to be nominalized (の) in order for で to attach to it?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5925/5010 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48065/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the grammar point meaning "without doing ~". It is constructed by using the plain-negative form of the verb (the ない form) and attaching the で particle to the end.

> 昨日は授業の後、家に帰らないで映画を観に行った。

The literal translation of this example would be "Yesterday after class, without returning home, I went to see a movie."

Here are some more examples:

> コーヒーには、いつも砂糖を入れないで飲みます。
> I always drink coffee without putting sugar in it.

> 彼女はカサを持たないで出てしまった。
> She left without bringing an umbrella.

> 朝ごはんを食べないで仕事に来ました。
> I came to work without eating breakfast.

> 夕食を食べないで、寝る。
> I go to sleep without eating dinner.

Additional resources:

- [Tae Kim](https://guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/inaction#Express_8220without_doing8221_with)
- [Bunpro](https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7)
- [JLPT Sensei](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7-naide-meaning/)

Comment: Literally speaking, do you know if で here has any relation to the particle で, or to the て-form of だ?

Comment: Yes it's the で particle in the same manner as doing something "with" like ハンマーで板を叩く (I hit the board *with* a hammer). In these examples, you're doing something *with* the negation of the verb, i.e. "with not eating", or "with not going home".

Comment: @George - [補説] 「ないで」については、打消しの助動詞「ない」に、助詞「で」、あるいは断定の助動詞「だ」の連用形「で」が付いて成ったとする説などがあり、いまだ定説をみない。また、「ないで」全体を接続助詞などとする扱いもある。2は、「お母さん、もうどこにも行かないで」のように文末に用いられることもある。([here](https://www.weblio.jp/content/ないで))